# Dart smartcast not working with two generics

Tags: dart, casting

I have class that takes to generics (for example `A` and `B`) and then i have a subclass which specifies one of those generics, like that:

```dart
class Foo<A, B>{
  void f() {}
}

class Boo<A> extends Foo<A, String> {
  void b() {}
}
```

When i am trying to cast a `Foo` variable to `Boo` the smart cast some how is not working:

```dart
void test<A, B>(Foo<A, B> foo) {
  if (foo is Boo<A>) 
     foo.b();
}
```

The error message is: `Error: The method 'b' isn't defined for the class 'Foo<A, B>'.`

But when i drop the generic types the function compiles:

```dart
void test(Foo foo) {
  if (foo is Boo) 
     foo.b();
}
```

Is there any way i can get the smart cast to work without dropping the generic types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as intended.

Dart only promotes variables to *subtypes* (a more precise type) to ensure that you don't lose information. That's why it's called "promotion", not just "casting".

When you do `foo is Boo<A>`, then it's checking whether `Boo<A>` is a subtype of the currently known type of the `foo` variable, which is `Foo<A, B>`.
It is not.
The type `Boo<A>` a subtype of `Foo<A, String>` (because it extends that), but `String` is not (statically known to be) a subtype of the type variable `B`. So as static types, `Boo<A>` is not a subtype of `Foo<A, B>`, and the promotion doesn't promote the static type of the `foo` variable.

There is not a lot you can do about this as written. The type `B` could be bound to `Never` at runtime, so no other type would be sound to assume to be a subtype of `B` at compile time.

When you drop the generics, the type of `foo` becomes `Foo<Object?, Object?>`, and any type implementing `Foo` is a subtype of that, so you do get promotion to `Bar<whatever>`.

If you declared `test` as:

```dart
void test<A>(Foo<A, String> foo) {
```

then the promotion would succeed.